# Contact Form Email Verification?

Tags: forms, email, contacts, verification, email-verification

recently I've been fighting with spammers on my sites and i managed to put under control the bots, but I am still facing human spammers.
My question is, has anyone managed to set-up a Contact Form email verification? Like, when you submit the form you receive a e-mail with a confirmation link that checks if the e-mail you are using is actually live not a spamming one.
All i found till now is this:
[GitHub Magician11's Plugin](https://github.com/magician11/wpcf7-email-verification/blob/master/wpcf7-email-verification.php) which by the description looks exactly as what im looking for, but the code/plugin hasn't been updated in 2 long years and is not working as required.
So, has anyone came across such a problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: You need to specify which language you are talking about. this has been set up many times by programmers. and it is easy but time consuming to do.

Comment: Oh, im using Wordpress CMS and Contact Form 7 Plugin. My coding skills are not something i could manage alone. If it was talked about before and set-up many times can you point me to the topics, as i have searched everywhere and couldnt manage to find anything.

Comment: Change the title and also tags to wordpress, php, form .. then you will receive a lot of help.... This site is for professioanl programmers and not helping public do their sites. we discuss bugs errors and not do the work each others work ... however as I have established you are not a programmer and this is purely plugin based. so search plugins and forums for such plugins or ask your question again with a appropriate title and tags please. Hope this will help.

Comment: You are not being helpful at all just rude, im not asking for you to solve my problem and i mentioned few times that i searched hard and all i found on the topic was the plugin i posted in my question, which is not updated. On your first answer you told me such problem was discussed and set-up many times before, so i asked if you could point me the right direction, setting up and making it work is my problem. I am looking for "experienced" people that have faced similiard problem. No plugin (working one) supports such thing nothing came in google also. Im sorry i bothered you with my question.

Comment: I am not trying to be rude or unhelpful! you got that completely wrong!
I will make it quick ... as mentioned this is a time consuming thing to write and it involves few things such as. Using PHP to send emails that requires you to set up a SMTP (If you want it done properly) so emails wont be flagged as spams. create Tokens with Hashes and send the email and wiat for the user to click on it and then compare it to the one in database. [See Here](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/09/login-registration-email-verification-forgot-password-php.html). It is called -from registration email verification-

Comment: Thanks, i will be looking into its implementation.